# How to stop/trick cmake into not rebuilding if a header file was changed then reverted?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

If I accidentally change a header file, save it,  and then change it back and re-save, how do I stop cmake from detecting the change and rebuilding all its dependencies.  Usually I don't even know it got modified until after I re-run `make` and it starts a rebuild process.

I've tried some naive manual timestamp changes, but had no luck.

To be clear, I'm looking for a hack or someone who can explain the rules cmake uses.   The environment is linux/os x using command line gcc/clang.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 that's what I meant by "I've tried some naive manual timestamp changes".   cmake seems to be smart about caching stuff somehow.. I don't think it even looks at the timestamps again after it determines things need to be rebuilt.  The answer probably involves changing timestamps and modifying certain files in CMakeFiles or something.

Comment: It unclear from the question if `CMake` detects modified files and re-runs configuration/generation or if it is `make` that rebuilds, when the header is modified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cmake` is a makefile generator (amongst other things it can generate). That's why you build with `make`.

The behavior you see is indeed standard `make` behavior. This is a generalized build tool; it rebuilds any "target" by applying the "recipe" for that target whenever the target is outdated. These targets and recipes have been written by `cmake`.

You can ask `make` which targets it would rebuild (`make --dry-run`) and update the timestamp of the header to predate all targets (`touch -r oldest_target header.h`). Alternatively, to avoid determining which target is oldest, alternate `make --dry-run` and  `touch -r` using the first target until `make --dry-run` returns no more targets.